# how to print the data from post request on console

Tags: node.js, express

### I am trying to print the post data on my console

---

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express')
 , http = require('http');

var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 7002);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/images'));


app.post('/Details/',function(request,response,next){


app.use(express.bodyParser());

   var keyName=request.query.Key;
   console.log(keyName);

} );


http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
 console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

---

### **Initial snapshot**::

[image]

---

### **I test with POST-MAN with below data**::

[image]

---

### **Now i get error as**::

[image]

---

- I just want to print the data i recieved from postman that is `dev`
  ..... which is being displayed as `undefined` ?
- How to resolve this !

---

### [Edit] ---- Adding body parser outside the route

```
var express = require('express')
 , http = require('http');

var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 7002);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/images'));

app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/Details/',function(request,response,next){

   var keyName=request.query.Key;
   console.log(keyName);

} );


http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
 console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

---

### Still have same error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [request.query](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query) when you have querystring params.

For form/post data use [req.body](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body).

In your case, use `request.body.key`.

Comment: It worked thanks .. i also posted the complete solution

Answer (score 13):

Instead of `query`:

```
var keyName=request.query.Key;
   console.log(keyName);
```

use `body`:

```
var keyName1=request.body.key;
console.log(keyName1);
```

---

Code:

```
var express = require('express')
 , async = require('async')
 , http = require('http');

var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 7002);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/images'));

app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/Details/',function(request,response,next){

   var keyName1=request.body.key;
   console.log(keyName1);
} );


http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
 console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: I just get a `Cannot POST / ` as a response from the server and nothing is printed in the console

Comment: @izzy That is because you need to have `app.post('/', ...)` in order to process post request for `/`.

Answer (score 10):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/post/', function(req, res) {
   // print to console
   console.log(req.body);

   // just call res.end(), or show as string on web
   res.send(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 4));
});

app.listen(7002);
```

Answer (score 2):

An update on using the middleware, `body-parser`, for later versions of Express: Using `app.use(express.bodyParser())` will report an error such as:
*Error: Most middleware (like bodyParser) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.*

This can be addressed by first installing the [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) middleware:

```
npm install body-parser
```

then write code such as:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

and then accessing the `body` of the `request` object, for example, `console.log(req.body)`

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `app.use(express.bodyParser());` inside middleware/route handler:

- request should pass through `bodyParser()` before it reaches route handler
- you will be adding new `bodyParser()`s in each request, but they will be after `app.router` and will never work

Comment: @ vkurchatkin ........ Please see the edit ......... still i have the same error, any inputs ?

Answer (score 1):

> Use built in function "util" to print any type of json data in express js

```
var util = require("util");
console.log(util.inspect(myObject, {showHidden: false, depth: null}));
```